# Organize resources in Java

Tags: java, resources

How can I organize resources in Java?

For example, when I will use pictures to be embedded in my application, in what folder can I store it? Because when I make my program in an executable .jar file all the resources like pictures, text file, it goes outside the folder where I stored it.

Comment: Traditionally, in a Maven build, all non-source resources live in `src/main/resources` and all Java files live in `src/main/java`. Maven then coalesces these locations, filtering the resources and compiling the Java files in the process. This means that the resources are on the classpath of the compiled application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common practice is to reserve a package to resources. You can place it anywhere, depending on the classes needing to access those resources (there's no rule, it's just a matter of organization logic). For example, your class `project.gui.Main` needs to load some images, you can then create a `project.gui.data` package and store your resources in it. To load these resources from `Main`, use the following piece of code :

```
Main.class.getResource("data/img.png");
```

This way, you can access the resource with a local path. Never use absolute paths if the application si expected to be packed in a jar.