# How to read the contents of a text file in <default.package> [Java]

Tags: java, file, import, libraries

Usually I can read the contents of a text file if it's just a regular file on my local disk. However, how can I read a file which exists in the default package I imported into my project? It doesn't have a filepath in the conventional sense so this is a little confusing.

Comment: You mean the default package of Eclipse ?

Comment: @Dici Yeah, but for netbeans. I have a text file which is in a `jar` that I added to the classpath as a library. I'm trying to use that text file.

Comment: See my answer to this question, if it can help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26084134/organize-resources-in-java/26084163#26084163

Comment: @Dici - worked for me, thanks! If you want to post it as an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When accessing a file within a jar, you cannot use absolute paths anymore. You must use the `getResource` (or `getResourceAsStream`) method defined on the `Class` class. More precisely, the call

```
MyClass.class.getResource(path)
```

will give access to the resource identified by the `String` variable `path`, which is a local path from the package containing `MyClass` to the resource. It is a common thing to create packages especially to store and access resources (for example a `myApp.data` package).