# How do i attach image in email? I am using AWS SES Service to send email using JAVA - Spring Boot

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application hosted on AWS. I am using AWS SES to trigger email. But i am lost as to how to attach an image using SES. I am using JAVA as application source code.The data are stored in the database but the email is not sent.:

```
   public void sendEmail(String to, String subject, String body) throws MessagingException {
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", PORT);
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);

        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        // the body content:
        messageBodyPart.setContent(BODY, "text/html");
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        // the image:
        messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(
                "Logo.png");
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
        messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image_01>");
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        // add the multipart to the message:
        msg.setContent(multipart);
        // set the remaining values as usual:
        try {
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(FROM, FROMNAME));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
        msg.setSubject(SUBJECT);

        Transport transport = session.getTransport();

        try {
            System.out.println("Sending...");
            transport.connect(HOST, SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_PASSWORD);
            transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
            System.out.println("Email sent!");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("The email was not sent.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            transport.close();
        }
    }
```

[image: project_structure]

[image: Error_Log]

Comment: You can use the [raw](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/examples-send-raw-using-sdk.html) interface and use standard [Java mail](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail) code.  What issues are you having?

Comment: I have not used the raw interface. when ever i try to add the image tag into my body it dose not pop up in the email. May be Raw interface out work out. i will try

Comment: Please provide some code. What have you tried, where do you get errors... See this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Simon I have added the code Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To embed an image into your e-mail, you need to make a couple of changes to your code. I tested these changes using an SES account, JavaMail and a gmail web client:

**Use the Content ID Scheme (`cid:`)**

Here is your body content using a `cid`:

```
static final String BODY = String.join(System.getProperty("line.separator"),
    "<html><head></head><body><img src=\"cid:image_01\"></html> <br>"
    + "Welcome to ABC and have a great experience.");
```

In this example, `image_01` is whatever identifier I want to use. When the mail is displayed, the `cid:` scheme means that the email client will look for a `Content-ID` header in the message, and retrieve the related image using that name - but the name will need to be enclosed in angle brackets `<` and `>` to be displayed inline (see below).

See more info [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2392).

**Create a Multipart Mime Message**

Your `MimeMessage msg` object will need to be built differently:

```
Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
try {
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    // the body content:
    messageBodyPart.setContent(BODY, "text/html");
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    // the image:
    messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    DataSource fds = new FileDataSource("/your/path/to/logo.png");
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
    messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image_01>");
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    // add the multipart to the message:
    msg.setContent(multipart);
    // set the remaining values as usual:
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(FROM, FROMNAME));
    msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
    msg.setSubject(SUBJECT);
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | MessagingException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Here we build a message consisting of two parts:

1. The HTML contents from `BODY`.
2. The image.

In my example, the image is a file on the filesystem - but you can access it in whatever way you need for your application (e.g. via a resource).

Note the use of angle brackets when setting the header (as mentioned earlier):

```
messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image_01>");
```

Now you can send the message in the usual way:

```
try ( Transport transport = session.getTransport()) {
    System.out.println("Sending...");
    transport.connect(HOST, SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_PASSWORD);
    transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
    System.out.println("Email sent!");
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

**A Note on `JavaMailSender`**

In your code, you include this:

```
private JavaMailSender mailSender;
```

which is Spring's wrapper around the JavaMail (now JakartaMail) object. You don't make use of this object in your code.

Given you are using Spring, I would recommend you get the above approach working, and then refactor your code to make use of Spring's mail helper utilities. There are lots of guides and tutorials for that elsewere.

**A Note on SES**

The above approach is using Amazon's [SES SMTP interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/examples-send-using-smtp.html). In other words, no need for any Amazon SDK classes in your code.

This is what I used when testing the code in this answer (using an SES account).

You can certainly look into using either of the other two approaches documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/examples-send-using-sdk.html) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/examples-send-raw-using-sdk.html) - but neither is required for images to be displayed.

---

**Update**

A question was asked, for clarification, about this:

```
messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image_01>");
```

The text `<image_01>` is how you refer to your image, in your HTML code. So, that is why my example code uses this:

```
<img src=\"cid:image_01\">
```

You can use any identifier you want here. In my case the identifier "image_01" refers to my image file "logo.png".

But just to be clear - you really do need to include the `<` and the `>` in your code. They are not there just as "placeholders" in my code - they are part of the syntax you need to use.

---

But remember, you can make everything much simpler, if you take full advantage of Spring, and the **Spring Mail Helper functions**.

For example, here is the same approach, using Spring's `JavaMailSender` and `MimeMessageHelper`:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MySpringMailer {

    static final String FROM = "donotreply@myaddress.com";
    static final String FROMNAME = "My Name";
    static final String TO = "my.email@myaddress.com";
    static final String SUBJECT = "Welcome to ABC";
    static final String BODY = String.join(System.getProperty("line.separator"),
            "<html><head></head><body><img src=\"cid:image_01\"></html> <br>"
            + "Welcome to ABC and have a really great experience.");

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    public void sendSpringEmailWithInlineImage() {
        MimeMessage msg = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        try {
            MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(msg, true); // true = multipart
            helper.setFrom(FROM, FROMNAME);
            helper.setTo(TO);
            helper.setSubject(SUBJECT);
            helper.setText(BODY, true); // true = HTML
            DataSource res = new FileDataSource("c:/tmp/logo.png");
            helper.addInline("image_01", res);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | MessagingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        javaMailSender.send(msg);
    }

}
```

So, for example, now we can create a reference for our image file using this:

```
helper.addInline("image_01", res);
```

Note that Spring does not need us to use `<` and `>` here, when we are defining the name in our Java code. Spring takes care of that  for us, behind the scenes.

Comment: i can understand. But can you please let me know on that to include in this part?
messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image_01>");

Comment: i tried both ways but i am unable to send any email. i am using SES for this feature
There is no error and my details are stored in the data base too. But the email part is not working

Comment: My advice: Start with a simple stand-alone Java program, which does not run in a web server, and which does not rely on a database (so, like the code from my examples above). In other words, start with the _simplest possible solution_.  You can try adding `mail.debug=true` as a setting - see if that gives you any insights. There are various reasons why e-mails may be created - and even sent successfully (no errors!) - but still  not received. Those reasons may have nothing to do with your code... Impossible for me to say, unfortunately.

Comment: I was able to check the log. And it says File not found exception when i give the image path

javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
  nested exception is:
        java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
this is how i gave my image
DataSource fds = new FileDataSource("Sample_Logo_GREEN.png");

My image is also in the same project folder and thus i didnt give the whole path

Comment: OK, as a test, put the file somewhere else, and provide the full path to its location: `FileDataSource("C:/path/to/Sample_Logo_GREEN.png)"`.

Comment: What does "it did not work" mean? What error did you get? If it is "file not found" again, which file is it saying was not found?

Comment: i cannot use my whole path as in c://path.....      i am running it in an ec2 instance. i have to build the projet and give relative path to my image like /projname/image.png. when i try to send the email it says /projname/image.png not found (file not found)

Comment: `/projname/image.png` is not a relative path - it starts with a slash - making it an absolute path from the root of the filesystem. Again, just for testing purposes you have lots of options - for example, you can pass in the path as a property variable. Then it can be different in your dev environemnt vs your EC2 environment.

Comment: Also, for a more robust approach, you can [read files from the project's classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26087801/how-to-read-the-contents-of-a-text-file-in-default-package-java), which means it won't matter that your development environment is different from your EC2 environment. But I recommend you do not try that until you get the simpler `FileDataSource` approach working.

Comment: Kindly see my post. i have edited the code and also added my project structure. i have tried multiple ways yet i am getting error.

Comment: What you show in your screenshots is clearly not going to work. Your file is inside your Spring application, with your _source_ code.  So I can't even see if it is deployed with the _compiled_ application or not. But regardless of that issue, the file needs to be on the filesystem (not inside the application) if you want to use `DataSource fds = new FileDataSource("Logo.png");`.

Comment: So i cannot use an image when i am using SES?

Comment: You can use SES. I _did_ use an image with SES in the code I show in this answer, and when I tested my code. You have 2 basic choices: (1) Put the file on the file system (not inside your app). You seem to be struggling to do that, for some reason. (2) Put the file inside the app (like you show in your screenshot), and study the link I provided above about how to read files from the project's classpath. But make sure the file is **copied to the classpath** - and does not just remain with the source code (where you have it in your screenshot) - otherwise option (2) will also not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code for sending an email through SES with embed an image as an attachment:

```
    String filePath = "src/main/resources/" + barcodeText + ".png";
    System.out.println("barcodeImg was saved in System locally");

    String subject = "test subject";
    String body = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n" + "<html>\n" + "    <head>\n" + "        <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n"
            + "        <title></title>\n" + "    </head>\n" + "    <body>\n" + "        <p>test</p>\n"
            + "        <p>-- BarCode from attachment<br><img src=\"cid:barcode\"></p><br>BarCode render completed\n"
            + "    </body>\n" + "</html>";
    String toAddrsStr = "emailID1, emailID2, emailID3";
    sendEmailWithAttachment(toAddrsStr, subject, body, filePath);
```

**Definition:**

```
public static void sendEmailWithAttachment(String to, String subject, String body, String attachmentFilePath) {
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(new Properties());
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    try {
        message.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("gowthamdpt@gmail.com"));
        //to address String should be with comma separated.
        message.setRecipients(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));

        MimeMultipart msg = new MimeMultipart("alternative");
        MimeBodyPart wrap = new MimeBodyPart();
        MimeMultipart msgBody = new MimeMultipart("mixed");

        MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        htmlPart.setContent(body, "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        msgBody.addBodyPart(htmlPart);
        wrap.setContent(msgBody);
        msg.addBodyPart(wrap);

        MimeBodyPart att = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(attachmentFilePath);
        att.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
        att.setFileName(fds.getName());
        att.setContentID("<barcode>");
        msg.addBodyPart(att);
        message.setContent(msg);

        AmazonSimpleEmailService client = AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();
        message.writeTo(System.out);
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        message.writeTo(outputStream);
        RawMessage rawMessage = new RawMessage(ByteBuffer.wrap(outputStream.toByteArray()));
        SendRawEmailRequest rawEmailRequest = new SendRawEmailRequest(rawMessage)
                .withConfigurationSetName(CONFIGSET);
        client.sendRawEmail(rawEmailRequest);
        System.out.println("sendEmail()" + "email triggered successfully");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("sendEmail()" + "The email was not sent. Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```