# Sending html email with css, js and images spring boot

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, email, thymeleaf

I have to send html to email but it has styles, images and js. I have button which calls my service POST method and send there some information so I have to attach js file anyway. I use thymeleaf and I tried to connect syles using url addres (like th:href=@{"https://localhost:8080/css/style.css"}) but it doesn't work. So how can I attach my css, js and images to html email?

Method I want to call using button:

```
@PostMapping(USER_CONFIRMATION_ENDPOINT)
    public String getConfirmUserRegistrationPage(@Valid @RequestBody ConfirmRegistrationDto confirmRegistrationDto) {

        emailService.confirmUserRegistration(confirmRegistrationDto);

        return "/accountActivationPage.html";
    }
```

My EmailService method:

```
private void sendLetter(User user, String subject, String link, String templatePath) {
        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariable("link", link);
        String htmlContent = templateEngine.process(templatePath, context);
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        try {
            MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "UTF-8");
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(htmlContent, true);
            message.setTo(user.getEmail());
            message.setFrom(emailProperties.getFrom());
        }
        catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);
    }
```

Comment: Regarding **embedded images**, you can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63648982/12567365) - specifically, the use of `MimeMessageHelper` with `helper.addInline("image_01", res);` at the end of the answer. You need to be careful how you refer to your image files, and use the reference names consistently. Also, if your images files are bundled in your application as resources, you can use `org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource` instead of `javax.activation.FileDataSource`.

Comment: Regarding **css and js resources**, I recommend embedding them directly in your message templates - so, in `<style>...</style>` tags and `<script>...</script>``` tags. Since you are using Thymeleaf, there are ways this can be implemented to support re-use of css and js files - for example, using [template fragments](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#including-template-fragments). But I think some e-mail clients may strip out or disable your scripts, in some cases.