# Thymeleaf : add image to email

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have tried these solutions :

```
<img th:src="@{/resources/images/logo.png}"/>
<img th:src="@{../images/logo.png}"/>
<img th:src="@{classpath:images/logo.png}"/>
```

In all cases I am getting a

```
Link base "/resources/images/logo.png" cannot be context relative (/)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: In general, for web pages: [Can I embed a .png image into an HTML page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2807251/12567365) but also, more specifically for your e-mail scenario: [How do i attach image in email...?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63625403/12567365). If you can make it work with "hard-coded" HTML in your template (just for testing the approach), then you should be able to make it work with the equivalent Thymeleaf in the same template.

Comment: (Thymeleaf may not even be relevant, unless you want to make the file name a variable.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding the image to an email, the `src` must be a URL. This means that the image must be accessible from the outside.

Comment: Ok, thx. Do you know if there is another way to insert 'physically' an image to an email?

Comment: Sure, you can do inline attachments for this.